# Redirect with array parameter Cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, redirect

I'm working on a Cakephp project, I have one controller that made some algorithms and save information to an array. I need to call another method on that same controller and send the array as a parameter. I need to do this using redirect, just like this:

```
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Identities', 'action' => 'myMethod', $array]);
```

If I don't use redirect, I will not have the view of the myMethod, and I need it, but I need to have the array information on that view, something like doing $this->set to pass the array to a view.

However, I get this error:

```
rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

How can I send the array as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use query string like this.

```
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Identities', 'action' => 'myMethod', '?' => ['param1' => 'val1', 'param2' => 'val2']]);
```

> You can provide routed elements or query string parameters.

[Source](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#508-645)

Comment: I have an array that have like 3000 elements, I cannot use that method since I would need to write all the elements, also the array can have different number of elements depending on the calculations. I need to pass the entire array as a parameter, similar to $this->set  function.

Comment: You can save elements to  session before redirect then load from session.

Comment: Good idea, I will give it a try and will let you know.